# RIGHT OUTER JOIN doesn't work with WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, where-clause, outer-join

Suppose I have two tables :

```
     CREATE TABLE `test_a` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And

```
CREATE TABLE `test_b` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `A_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Amount` float NOT NULL,
  `cat` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `test_b_ibfk_1` (`A_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `test_b_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`A_id`) REFERENCES `test_a` (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

In test_a I entered data

1, A 
2, B  
3, C

In second table I entered following data:
1, 1, 4.78, 1 
2, 2, 77, 1 
3, 1, 0.22, 1 
4, 2, 13, 1

The task is:  to select sum of all amounts, grouped by a_id, all data from test_a must be appear.
Thus, I’m using right outer join. 
When I ran following query:

```
SELECT a.name, sum(b.amount)
  FROM test_b AS b RIGHT OUTER JOIN test_a AS a ON b.A_id = a.id
 GROUP BY b.A_id;
```

That gives a result set as desired. Like this:
C --  null 
A --  5 
B --  90

But when I used WHERE clause:

```
          SELECT a.name, sum(b.amount)
          FROM test_b AS b RIGHT OUTER JOIN test_a AS a ON b.A_id = a.id
          **where b.cat =1**
           GROUP BY b.A_id;
```

I get the result:
A --  5 
B --  90

My question is: How to achieve same result with WHERE clause. (I want ‘C – null’, to be appear)

Thank in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got to include your condition of the joined table b in the ON condition:

```
SELECT a.name, sum(b.amount) 
FROM 
    test_b AS b 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
    test_a AS a 
ON 
    b.A_id = a.id AND b.cat =1 
GROUP BY b.A_id;
```

Because if used in the WHERE clause it changes the OUTER JOIN implicitly to an INNER JOIN.

Comment: Thank a lot, VMai It was usefull, I'll mark it, but cann't vote up due to my small reputation, sorry.